# System bootorder not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, uefi

I already had Windows 10 installed on my PC. Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows. After completing the installation the PC is unable to boot; I get this message at startup:

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
Creating boot entry "Boot000B" with label "ubuntu" for file "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"

Reset System
```

I get the same message every time I boot.

It is important to note that I installed Windows in Legacy BIOS mode where as the Ubuntu was installed using EFI. Now, there are separate BIOS modes for each system and I am unable to boot Windows even from "Boot from File" option in the "Boot Order menu". When I boot from the legacy boot entry of Windows in boot order it says boot device not found please install operating system. I am using HP Elitebook 840 G2.

This is how the partitions on my disk are configured:

```
Device     Type     Mount point
/dev/sda1  ntfs
/dev/sda2  ntfs
/dev/sda3  efi
/dev/sda5  swap
/dev/sda6  ext4     /
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is exactly your issue, but I ran into the same error when I installed Mint for dual-booting with Windows. My HP laptop had the option in

- UEFI > Boot options > Advanced

to add a Customized Boot.

It allows you to enter a path and that's where I added `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`.

Then I changed the boot order to have Customized Boot on top and it booted into GRUB magically. If you can do something similar, this may just solve the issue for you.