# System bootorder not found -

Tags: linux-mint, grub, rescue

I tried to install Linux Mint Cinnamon on my Acer laptop, but after the installation there comes up a grub bootloader screen with this text.

https://ibb.co/P9r0hpw

So what can I do? It's now enough for me if I can start my old Windows partition. Can I rescue my old system?

Old System: Windows 10 Bios Legacy Mode

Installation from Linux Mint in EFI mode.

Comment: does this answer your question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/585537/72456

Comment: No i cant add somewhere other options

Comment: You cannot mix Windows BIOS boot on MBR partitioned drive and UEFI boot of Ubuntu that really should be on a gpt drive. Windows requires boot flag on its primary NTFS partition with boot files, often sda1. But UEFI will have boot & ESP flags on the efi system partition (FAT32). You can only have one boot flag per drive. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option).
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Hello again. I dont understand what to do and have now one question. Can I install only a new windows version? I mean i want to kill and format the whole system and install a new windows version? Will this been easier? And how can i do?